# fs.readdirSync is not a function というエラーがでる

Tags: javascript, node.js

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112204/get-all-directories-within-directory-nodejs

と

[特定ディレクトリ配下のファイルのみ(またはディレクトリのみ)を取得（Node.js v10.10以降版) - Qiita](https://qiita.com/takeyuichi/items/65477e9c8ff5cfc6fdef)

と

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43622386/1979953

を参考に下記のコードを書きました（コードはほとんどQiitaの記事のままです）。

```
const dirPath = "./pages/";
const allDirents = fs.readdirSync(dirPath, { withFileTypes: true });
const fileNames = allDirents.filter(dirent => dirent.isFile()).map(({ name }) => name);
console.log(fileNames)
```

インポート文を

```
import { promises as fs } from "fs"
```

とすると、

```
const allDirents = fs.readdirSync(dirPath, { withFileTypes: true });
                      ^

TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function
```

というエラーがでます。

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

とすると、エラーはなくなり、コードは正常に動きます。

現在コードを改良しており、既存コードは `await` を使っているので、

```
import { promises as fs } from "fs"
```

で書きたいのですが、不可能なのでしょうか？　そもそもなぜこのようなエラーが出ているのでしょうか？

また

```
import {fs} from 'fs';
```

とした場合は

```
import {fs} from 'fs';
        ^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'fs' does not provide an export named 'fs'
```

というエラーです。

> Or in case the module has named exports:
> import {fs} from 'fs';

とあったので、いけそうな気がしたのですが無理だったようです。

```
import { promises as fs } from "fs"
```

とした場合はインポート自体は成功しているので、このような違いがでる理由がわかりません。

実行環境：

上記コード自体は拡張子を `.mjs` にしており、

package.json の scripts は下記のようにしています

```
  "scripts": {
    "render": "node --es-module-specifier-resolution=node render.mjs",
```

起動方法：

```
npm run render
```

### まとめ

まとめると下記になります

- `import * as fs from 'fs';` だと成功
- `import {fs} from 'fs';`と`import { promises as fs } from "fs;"` がエラーになる理由が知りたい（しかもそれぞれエラー内容が違う）
- 理想は既存コードに上記コードを足したいので　`import { promises as fs } from "fs;"`　が使いたい

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript のモジュールは、以下を export します。

- default の何かしら
- 名前が付いた何かしら

`import * as fs from 'fs';` とは、「名前が付いた export をすべて import し、それらを `fs.名前` でアクセスできるようにしろ」という構文です。

`import {fs} from 'fs';` とは、「`fs` の名前が付いた何かしらを `fs` の名前でアクセスできるようにしろ」という構文です。

`import { promises as fs } from "fs;"` とは、「`promises` の名前がついた何かしらを `fs` の名前でアクセスできるようにしろ」という構文です。

それぞれやっていることが違うので、動作は当然に違ってきます。

---

やりたいことが、「`promises`の名前で export されたものを `fs` でアクセスしながら `readdirSync` も使いたい」ということでしたら、

`import { promises as fs, readdirSync } from 'fs';` を実行しながら、 `readdirSync` は直接(`fs.`のプレフィックスをつけずに)利用するといけるような気がしています。